# HTML/CSS @media Query : The line keeps disappearing

Tags: html, css

I couldn't understand the part of studying CSS.
If I decrease the browser size, the line disappears. 
I don't know why. 
Can't I keep the line from disappearing?
I have no idea why it's disappearing.
Please help me.

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
 nav {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  border: solid 1px skyblue;
}

section {
  margin-left:25%;
  border: solid 1px orange;
} 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  nav li {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Taco Menu</li>
        <li>Draft List</li>
        <li>Hours</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero odit, dolorem dolore, porro repudiandae animi iusto, quia quae autem voluptate minus ducimus cupiditate ipsum! Fugit assumenda error veritatis pariatur expedita.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad fugiat, nulla officiis quibusdam iusto non. Sint suscipit pariatur aspernatur amet iusto aperiam est nesciunt ullam. Labore sit, ut ipsum neque.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Somewhere you are removing the border in media query, please check that

Comment: You have used min-width that means the css will be applied to only devices or screen who have width of more than 600 `@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
 nav {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  border: solid 1px skyblue;
}

section {
  margin-left:25%;
  border: solid 1px orange;
} 
}` You need to add this `nav {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  border: solid 1px skyblue;
}

section {
  margin-left:25%;
  border: solid 1px orange;
} ` CSS inside max-width also.

Answer (score 2):

Just write `border` CSS separate to media query so that media query style does not overwrite it. Go through below code or try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b91n23Lz/313/).

CSS CODE-

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

nav {
  border: solid 1px skyblue;
}

section {
  border: solid 1px orange;
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
  nav {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }
  section {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  nav li {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to the lines around the nav and the section.

Keep in mind that the media queries for your page over 600px will not apply when your page is less than that amount - therefore if you want to retain the lines around the nav and section, the css for the borders should be placed outside of the @media (like you have with your container).